# Continued gestures/strokes on Android 7

Tags: android, accessibility, gesture

Continued strokes is introduced in Android 8.0. But Anydesk can reproduce such on Android 7.0. How does he do it? I tried adding another long stroke to each gesture, which essentially does nothing, but it didn't help

```
touchPath.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
touchPath.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
duration = (timeStamp - lastTimeStamp) / 1000;
stroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(touchPath, 0, duration);

fakePath = new Path();
fakePath.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
fakeStroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(fakePath, duration, 30000);

...

GestureDescription gesture = builder.build();
builder.addStroke(stroke);
builder.addStroke(fakeStroke);
dispatchGesture(gesture, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is relevant to the question but this was a bug in TalkBack, not Android (I know because I reported it). So it's not a matter of what version of Android you are using but actually the version of TalkBack, because TalkBack is just an app. So it could be that the device just needs to update TalkBack. If AnyDesk was able to do it, they may have written their own accessibility service and provided hooks to perform gestures in another way - or even compiled their own version of [TalkBack from source](https://github.com/google/talkback) with additional hooks. That's what I would do (and it's what Samsung does).

I have summarized the [(kotlin) code I wrote](https://github.com/qbalsdon/accessibility_broadcast_dev/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/balsdon/accessibilityDeveloperService/AccessibilityDeveloperService.kt) below. I modified a lot of it from the [Android Accessibility Service codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service#0).

I noticed that they use static distance numbers and timings, which is disappointing. Initially I was measuring the screen dimensions, but that stopped working for me.

```
private const val MAX_POSITION = 1000f
private const val MIN_POSITION = 100f

data class GestureAction(val path: Path, val startTime: Long = 0, val duration: Long = 500)

fun createGestureFrom(gestureAction: GestureAction): GestureDescription {
    return GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(
        GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(
            gestureActions[0].path,
            gestureActions[0].startTime,
            gestureActions[0].duration,
            gestureActions.size > 1)
        ).build()
}

// https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#continued-gestures
fun swipeUpRight() {
    val swipeUpAndRight = Path().apply {
        moveTo(MIN_POSITION, MAX_POSITION)
        lineTo(MIN_POSITION, MIN_POSITION)
        lineTo(MAX_POSITION, MIN_POSITION)
    }
    performGesture(GestureAction(swipeUpAndRight))
}

private fun performGesture(gestureAction: GestureAction) =
        dispatchGesture(
            createGestureFrom(gestureAction),
            GestureResultCallback(),
            null
        )
```